# C++ Library Does Not Link in Release Configuration (VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

I've been trying to get static libraries (`.lib` files) to work in VS2010, and I have it working perfectly in the debug configuration.  When I try to compile it under the release configuration, however, I get the error `error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Library.h': No such file or directory`.

Here's the current scenario:

- I have a `.lib` file and a `.h` file in a folder on my desktop called `Static Library`.
- I have the INCLUDE environment variable pointed to the aforementioned folder (so I can use `#include <Library.h>`).
- I have the LIB environment variable pointed to the aforementioned folder as well.
- I have added the `.lib` file as an additional dependency and set the directory for additional dependencies.

My source code for the test program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <Library.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << Library::GetValue(); // Returns 123.
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you set the compiler settings and paths for the Release configuration?  (Note that you can set the settings differently for different configurations.)

Comment: @James Looks like that was the problem.  Is there a way to link the two sets of configuration settings together, or will I just have to remember to do it twice for each project?

Comment: At the top of the project configuration dialog, you can select which configurations you are modifying the settings for.  One option is "All Configurations" (or something to that effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about VS2010... but the debug and release modes probably have different library settings...

You can inform the compiler to link thru code by specifying the following

```
#pragma comment(lib, "library.lib") // no ; is needed
```

That will make it link in both debug and release

Comment: Indeed, it appears as though the debug and release configuration settings are independent.  Also, does the `#pragma` work in other compilers as well?

Comment: I believe so, never had a problem with it yet